# I cant make my code to run and i dont know what is wrong

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the problem of uri online judge (problem 1318) in c.

```
#include < stdio.h >

int main() {
    int N, M, a[M], i, j, fake;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%d %d", & N, & M);
        fake = 0;

        if (N == 0 && M == 0) {
            break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            scanf("%d", & a[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < M - 1; i++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < M; j++) {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                    fake = fake + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", fake);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this code is showing runtime error... I dont know how to fix this and I am not sure if anything is wrong in my code.

Comment: 'int N, M, a[M],' - no, use of initintialized var to size VLA:(

Comment: use like this   #include <stdio.h>

Comment: What is your input? What is the expected and the actual output?

Comment: M has junk value. Making an array with junk value as its size will make the program behavior undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M` is **uninitialized**!
Read `M` before creating the array `a` or, make `a` big enough to contains all possible input sizes and use `M` to limit the access to `a`. The latter this is quite common in competitive programming: create a static array big enough and then use only a portion of it based on other information, like `M` in this case.

Anyway, the error would be easily spotted enabling compiler warnings `Wall -Wextra`:
Here is what `gcc`, `clang` and `icc` complains about.

```
 gcc   -Wall -Wextra -g -O3 -Wshadow  test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:1: warning: ‘M’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
 int N, M, a[M], i, j, fake;

             ^~~
```

---

```
 clang   -Wall -Wextra -g -O3 -Wshadow  test.c
test.c:7:13: warning: variable 'M' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
int N, M, a[M], i, j, fake;

           ^
test.c:7:9: note: initialize the variable 'M' to silence this warning
int N, M, a[M], i, j, fake;
            ^
         = 0
1 warning generated.
```

---

```
 icc   -Wall -Wextra -g -O3 -Wshadow  test.c
test.c(7): warning #592: variable "M" is used before its value is set
  int N, M, a[M], i, j, fake;
```